# How can I avoid these "hotspots" in mesh gradients in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, gradient, gradient-mesh

In Inkscape v1.1 on Ubuntu, I can apply a mesh gradient to an object's fill. Cool! However, even when I set the color for all the node handles in the mesh, I still get what I can only describe as "hotspots": places where the mesh gradient doesn't seem to be responding to the colors that I've set.

[image: Hexagon with a rainbow gradient mesh. Some of the gradients incorporate colors not set in the mesh.]

In this example, for instance, the three-pointed purple flare at the center (and stretching out along the yellow segment) baffles me. The color of the center point is set to white. The two handles along the yellow edge are both set to the same yellow, and the two handles along the green edge are set to the same green. I can see no place where that purple is defined in the mesh gradient, at least using the graphical controls given to me. And yet, it's present.

What is causing these problems with the mesh gradient, and how can I fix them so that colors transition smoothly throughout the entire mesh, and there are no "hotspots" of colors not defined by the mesh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is difficult to resolve because of the way meshes are constructed, making it a rather tricky edit.

If you pull apart the mesh, you will discover that there are in fact seven overlapping stops in the centre, and two additional overlapping stops where the mesh meets itself.

So, to fix it you'd need to select those stops, recolour them, then put it all back together again.

Example

[image]

Comment: Oh, wow, that's really obnoxious and seems to introduce a lot of imprecision. Bummer. Thanks for the answer, though!

Comment: @SpencerDub There are ways to deal with the imprecision, for example placing a guide to mark the centre, and snapping to the guide for moving the stops back on top of each other. It's definitely tricky though.